# CSS/HTML : how to make something become absolute positioned once you scroll by it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to CSS and HTML here and I'm trying to learn how to make something become absolutely positioned once you scroll by it on the page.

Here's an example of what I mean: http://fab.com/help/ (you don't need an account to scroll). When you scroll down, the black menu bar at the top disappears and the white menu bar with "How can we help you" becomes absolutely positioned.

I created a an example with a similar menu system,

http://jsfiddle.net/jkdbP/

but I don't know where to start to make it become absolutely positioned once it's scrolled by, thanks a lot for any insights!

Comment: Have you tried to dissect `http://fab.com/help?` to figure it out?

Comment: Probably they don't share that info, but using FireBug it was simple to see how it works.

Comment: Remy Sharp has a very nice screencast on how to do this http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkdbP/2/

```javascript
var menuTop = $('.menu').offset().top;
var menuClone = $('.menu').clone().addClass('fixed');

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var scrollY = window.pageYOffset;

    if(scrollY > menuTop) {
        if(menuClone.parent().length === 0) {
            menuClone.appendTo($('.menu').parent());
        }
    } else if(menuClone.parent().length > 0) {
        menuClone.remove();
    }
});
```

You can use jQuery's `.offset().top` to get the Y-position of your menu, and `window.pageYOffset` (or `document.body.scrollTop` for old IE compatibility) to get the page's scroll offset. You can then handle the `window`'s `scroll` event.

Comment: Also for the OP: Make sure you play with the positioning of the rest of the content, as `position:fixed` effectively tears the element off the document flow, hence the small jump of the content when the menu starts floating, as they re-flow to fill up the menu's space. It becomes more noticeable if you use a taller menu element.

Comment: @DarthJDG: I updated the answer with a solution that has no jumping.

Answer (score 0):

Read about CSS [`position`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) attribute and jQuery [`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) method