# Position fixed menu to top

Tags: css

I know how to use `position:fixed;` but I want, if the page scrolls over it, that it's on the top and on normal state lower.

```
.menu {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are working with.

Comment: .menu {
 height:30px;
 width:100%;
 border-bottom:1px solid black;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
}

Comment: And it has to be on 300px of the top, but when the page cross the menu it has to stick at 0px of the top.

Comment: Please post the rest of it if you could... you're not giving us anything to work with.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to make a menu fixed after it's scrolled past? If that's the case, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249408/css-html-how-to-make-something-become-absolute-positioned-once-you-scroll-by-i/8249501#8249501).

If that doesn't work for you, consider using code like this, assuming jQuery (actually [Sprint](https://github.com/minitech/Sprint2) but it's about the same for both):

```javascript
var navigation = $('nav').item(0);
var navigationY = navigation.element.offsetTop;
var navClone = navigation.clone();

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var scrollY = (window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop) >>> 0;
    if(scrollY > navigationY) {
        if(!navClone.element.parentNode || navClone.element.parentNode.nodeType !== 1) {
            navigation.after(navClone);
            navigation.addClass('fixed');
        }
    } else if(navClone.element.parentNode) {
        navClone.remove();
        navigation.removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

which I used in a recent project, so just change `$('nav')` at the top to whatever you need to select your element, e.g. `$('.menu')`.