# How to make a div "stick" to the top of the page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make one of those things similar to the stackoverflow orange messages at the top, if you scroll down the page the message gets fixed to the top" and when you are scrolled back up for it to be in view it resumes being fixed and goes back to being displayed as block.

Anyway here is my attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/cXP2y/

HTML:

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;height:50px;width:100%">Header</div>
<div id="message">Message</div>

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

CSS:

```
#message { padding: 10px; background: #06c; }
.message-fixed { position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; }
```

jQUery:

```
$(function() {

var message = $('#message');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > (message.offset().top + message.height())) {
        message.addClass('message-fixed');
    }
    else {
        message.removeClass('message-fixed');
    }
});

});
```

As you can see it has that flicker happening. How can I prevent this?

Also is there a more optimized way to write my code?

Comment: Frankly I don't understand... why not just to sctick to the CSS position:fixed (without the JS.) ? anyway it's place is there, on the top, right?

Comment: @roXon I am using position fixed, but without the js when the user scrolls back up to the top it won't resume to going back to being displayed as block. It's a certain effect a lot of sites use, including stackoverflow and okcupid. That's what I'm going for.

Comment: Where do you see it on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @minitech when you get a new badge, maybye it's in other spots as well.

Comment: Oh, that. It stays at the top the whole time, doesn't it? It doesn't ever resume `display: block`. But I think I see what you mean, read my answer.

Comment: @minitech nah it doesn't just stick to the top. It has that behavior. Anyway the 2nd link you posted does exactly what I need without the flicker. Will pick that as best ans in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of questions about this lately...

See my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281293/position-fixed-menu-to-top/8281352#8281352) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249408/css-html-how-to-make-something-become-absolute-positioned-once-you-scroll-by-i/8249501#8249501). Since you're using jQuery, it's very convenient - handle `window`'s `scroll` event, get the element's `offset`, clone it, and add or remove the appropriate class.

Comment: 2nd link has the ans. in case anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: Instead of referencing other SO posts in your answer you should be marking this question as a duplicate to those and closing it out.

Comment: @Keith.Abramo: I was waiting to make sure they were actually duplicates, first. The question wasn't exactly clear on that.